# Header: Section on the left, subsection (if existent) on the right

Tags: sectioning, formatting, header-footer, fancyhdr, article

I have got two questions and would be extremely grateful for any help (especially with the first question)!

**Question 1:** I am using the `article class` and would like the section title (including section number) to appear on the LEFT; additionally, on pages belonging to a subsection, the subsection title (excluding number) should be printed on the RIGHT.

To create the header I used the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\lhead{\sectionmark}
\rfoot{\centering \thepage}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Chapter 2}
  \subsection{A subsection}
  \subsection{Another subsection}

\section{Chapter 3}
  \subsection{First subsection in Chapter 3}
  \subsection{Another subsection in Chapter 3}

\section{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

The **problem** is that with this code, the left-hand header is empty and the right-hand header gives the subsection title (if a subsection exists) and otherwise it gives the section title.

I would be very grateful if someone would show me how to get the desired header, described above!

**Question 2:** I don't want the header to appear on the first page of a new section. Is there anything one could include in the preamble to achieve this, instead of having to add `\thispagestyle{empty}`in the code underneath each `\section`command?

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: it would be easier to answer if you made your example run without error and  have pages showing the problem. But note by default `article` is one-sided and only the odd (right hand) page style is used, you need `[twoside]` to enable left and right pages to be styled differently.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you so much – this was the piece I was missing!